# Cannot scan file for errors using eslint in angular 6 with project using eslint-plugin-angularjs-security-rules

Tags: angular, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb, typescript-eslint

I'm very new to eslint and one of my client asked to preform security check using Eslint and asked to use AngularJS Security Rules For ESLint (https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-angularjs-security-rules). I'm not clear what is the correct process to follow to preform this task, I have angular 6 project.
I did following steps
1. npm i eslint-plugin-angularjs-security-rules
2. update package.json file adding  "eslint": "^4.16.0"
3. ran npm i
4. created .eslintrc file and added following code

```
{ 
"env" : {
  "browser" : true,
  "es6" : true 
},
"plugins" : [
  "angularjs-security-rules"
],
"rules" : {


  "angularjs-security-rules/detect-angular-trustAs-methods": 1,
  "angularjs-security-rules/detect-angular-trustAsHtml-method": 1,
  "angularjs-security-rules/detect-angular-trustAsCss-method": 1,
  "angularjs-security-rules/detect-angular-trustAsUrl-method": 1,
  "angularjs-security-rules/detect-angular-trustAsJs-method": 1,
  "angularjs-security-rules/detect-angular-trustAsResourceUrl-method": 1,
  "angularjs-security-rules/detect-angular-open-redirect": 1,
  "angularjs-security-rules/detect-angular-element-methods": 1,
  "angularjs-security-rules/detect-angular-orderBy-expressions": 1,
  "angularjs-security-rules/detect-angular-resource-loading": 1,
  "angularjs-security-rules/detect-angular-sce-disabled": 1,
  "angularjs-security-rules/detect-angular-scope-expressions": 1,
  "angularjs-security-rules/detect-angular-service-expressions": 1,
  "angularjs-security-rules/detect-third-party-angular-translate": 1
}
```

}

I don't have any clue after this to use eslint commands to scan my code repo and find errors.